# Создание файла

Tags: php, html, javascript, css

Возможно ли с помощью **PHP**, **Javascript** или еще чего-нибудь сделать такой функционал, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку в папке с сайтом создавался файл, например, **file.txt**???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
//путь и сам файл
$file = "text.txt";
//если файла нету... тогда
if (!file_exists($file)) {
    $fp = fopen($file, "w"); // ("r" - считывать "w" - создавать "a" - добовлять к тексту),мы создаем файл
    fwrite($fp, "Значение, то что будет в файле");
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

Comment: Для этого случая, все это - неоправданный геморрой. Достаточно:

      file_put_contents('text.txt', 'Тест в файл', FILE_APPEND);

FILE_APPEND нужен для того, что-бы не переписывать текст файла, а дописывать в него (если убрать, то, собственно, содержимое файла будет переписываться). Если файл 'text.txt' не существует - он будет создан.

PS: 2 @kostya - а вот оскорблений и матов здесь не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная функция PHP - [fopen()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fopen.php).

Если у вас Win Server, то можно через ActiveX воспользоваться методом [CreateTextFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c(v=VS.84).aspx), объекта FileSystemObject.

Answer (score 1):

$create = fopen("file.txt", "a");